# Is there an http web server R package that can be stopped programmatically when a specific condition becomes true?

Tags: r, http, server

I need to run a web server in R to respond to a single http request to a given endpoint (e.g. /stop), and after responding to that request, stop the web server and do further processing.
It seems to me most web servers are designed not to be stopped programmatically.
I tried plumber, httpuv, Rook but could not find how to stop them other than by a manual action such as pressing Ctrl+C.

Comment: Consider using a supervisor outside of R, including `systemctl` and `supervisor`. Allow the user-id that is running the shiny/plumber/web-server thingy the ability to stop the service using a `system(.)` call (or, since I really hate that function, I tend to use `processx::run`).

Comment: Thanks @r2evans so you mean there is no http web server R package with an integrated function that could be called to stop the server, correct ?

Comment: Well, `shiny::stopApp` stops the current _app_ (not the server), that's the most I know of an R-based service self-stopping, and it is incomplete.It seems rather _Inception_-like to want to do that, frankly I don't know of a non-R web server that allows a child process to stop the whole thing. The best I can think of is in my first comment.